# Cannot send file from browser to remote server using Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I've got a servlet running on a remote Linux server with Tomcat 9. The servlet waits for data from javascript function.
Here the code

```
function uploadFile(file,numfiles){

var data;   
var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     data = reader.result;
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

            numprogressivo=numprogressivo+1;
            if (numprogressivo==numfiles){
                alert ("sent data to servlet");
                window.location.href = "SetNumFile";
            }
        }
      };


        xhttp.open("POST", "AddXmlInCartella", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('upload_file=' + data);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     alert('Error: ', error);
   };
```

this code works in localhost Tomcat server, but it doesnt on Remote server.

I need help to find the bug, what could be differences between localhost and remote server? The application doesnt communicate any error, when I attach files it doesnt anything.

Comment: the path to your servlet might be different on your remote server. Try something like:

xhttp.open("POST", "../../AddXmlInCartella", true);

Comment: just try to access the relevant remote serverlet address from browser and check the status code.